# Pytesseract: Cannot read digits on a relatively good quality image

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have an image as below:

[image]

With tesseract command:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(box_img_6, config="--lang= 'eng' --psm 6 --oem 3")
```

I am getting the output: 'nu  '

I think tesseract should perform better on this image and at least read some of the digits.

Can you help me to improve the performance of Tesseract?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = (r"C:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(r"a.jpg"), lang='eng',
                        config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')

print(text)
```

Output

```
**3008**
```

Comment: Hi tahnks for the answer. Can I learn your version of tesseract, because I am not getting the same result.

Comment: Yes, Drop your mail. I will send you tesseract zip binary files. Later you can add path to code by copying the path of extracted file

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#image-processing):

But for the input image, you don't need apply any pre-processing or set any configuration parameters, the result of:

```py
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray_image)
```

will be:

```
3008
```

in the current-latest version of pytesseract ([0.3.7](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/))

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("wwckp.jpg")

# Convert to the gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# OCR
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry)
print(txt)
```